# static int in c#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace LearnThread
{
    class Delay
    {
        public int timePass()
        {
            static int i=0;
            for(i=0; i<100;i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

> Error:The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item

Why static is error here? We cannot use static for int as we can use in C language?

Comment: Because C# is not C.

Comment: How do you expect a static local variable _inside_ of an instance method to behave?

Comment: Also, what's the point of that `i` being static there anyway?

Comment: @Matthew, David: He already said, he's just learning... So this is probably just code to play around to better understand how the C# language works.

Comment: @m-y I didn't mean to be rude about the question, I just assumed that in writing `static` they intended to do something that a non-static variable couldn't.

Comment: @Matthew: I wasn't saying it as if you were being rude, just putting in a comment at the top so other readers understand the **why**.

Comment: +1 from me for the question: it was a useful question to ask, as other  people (like me) also wondered whether you could do this in C#.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't declare a locally scoped variable as `static`, which is what you are doing.

You can create a static field or static property for a class (i.e. it is a member of a class), which would reside **outside** of a method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace LearnThread
{
    class Delay
    {
        static int i=0;

        public int timePass()
        {
            for(i=0; i<100;i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Though, this code seems kinda dumb... why bother using a static field in a for-loop iteration? It can cause a lot of issues with multiple calls to the method. I presume that you're either learning C# by playing around with crazy code, or you are trying to solve another problem and threw this code in. Either that or.... you're doing it wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not define static variable *inside* the `function`, only on `class` level.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a static variable inside a method since it would go out of scope when returning from the method body. Move it to the class level and static ints are fully available.

Answer (score 1):

> Static Variable:A field declared with the static modifier is called a
>   static variable. A static variable comes into existence before
>   execution of the static constructor.
>
> To access a static variable, you must "qualify" where you want to use
>   it. Qualifying a member means you must specify its class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace LearnThread
{
    class Delay

    {
        static int i=0;

        public int timePass()
        {

            for(i=0; i<100;i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```